# Rename [revenue-cat] to [revenuecat]

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags, retag-request

We at [RevenueCat](https://www.revenuecat.com/) were about to create the tag [revenuecat](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/revenuecat) to comprise the questions regarding our SDK and products, and noticed that [revenue-cat](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/revenue-cat) was already created.

Is it a fair thing to ask for to rename the existing [revenue-cat](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/revenue-cat) tag to [revenuecat](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/revenuecat) so that it can be used correctly from now on?

Comment: There was one question with it, so I burned it. The system will nuke the tag the new one can be applied. Or a mod can do it now. Not sure how long until the tag gets deleted :/

Comment: Good thing you only touched the tag on that question, @Will. Wouldn't want to risk anything happening to that shining example of how *not* to ask a debugging question.

Comment: The wound... tis not deep, but it will do.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It does make more sense to not have the hyphen in the name if the company's original name does not have spaces or hyphens. Therefore [revenuecat](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/revenuecat) is the better name for the tag.

There was only one post with that tag, and [Will removed it](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/379972/rename-revenue-cat-to-revenuecat#comment668828_379972). I went ahead and added the [revenuecat](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/revenuecat) tag to it. At 3UTC tomorrow, the earlier [revenue-cat](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/revenue-cat) will be deleted.